# How can I make Putty SCP not prompt about connecting to a new device?

Tags: command-line, python, putty, pscp

I am attempting to use the Putty SCP program to copy files to a server.  I am launching it with a Python subprocess:
`subprocess.check_output(pscp + ' -r -l ' + self._properties['ssh user'] + ' -pw ' + self._properties['ssh password'] + ' -4 -batch ' + local_path + ' ' + self._properties['ssh user'] + '@' + self._properties['target ip'] + ':' + destination_dir)`

Which resolves correctly to the following command:
`pscp -r -l root -pw password -4 -batch projects\packages\controller-fw\build\packager\controller-fw-iMx6-release root@10.52.120.201:/root/temp`

What I am seeing is it abort the connection:

```
error   26-Apr-2019 14:35:28    The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You
error   26-Apr-2019 14:35:28    have no guarantee that the server is the computer you
error   26-Apr-2019 14:35:28    think it is.
error   26-Apr-2019 14:35:28    The server's ssh-ed25519 key fingerprint is:
error   26-Apr-2019 14:35:28    ssh-ed25519 255 b9:a3:75:d7:c5:73:68:37:5d:6c:d1:61:6f:57:b4:ab
```

Is there a way to automatically accept the SSH key stuff?  I had hoped using the -batch option would resolve it, but all it does is make it abort.  I have looked into preceding it with a `plink` call, but it isn't clear from the manual that it would behave any differently.  Is there a correct way to do this?

Just before people ask, I am switching away from Paramiko due to poor performance reasons.  It takes > 5 minutes to upload files that FileZilla can do in 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`-hostkey` switch](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-hostkey) to specify a fingerprint of the expected host key:

```
pscp.exe -hostkey aa:bb:cc... ...
```

Comment: Is there any way of determining this hostkey beforehand?  It isn't always the same device on the other end, which would have a different hostkey, so I would need to determine it dynamically

Comment: If it could have been done dynamically, then pscp would NOT ask for it. Verifying the host key is integral part of securing your SSH connection. It's there to protect your from the [Man-in-the-middle attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

Comment: See also my article [Where do I get SSH host key fingerprint to authorize the server?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_hostkey) - it's about WinSCP, but in general it applies to any SSH/SFTP/SCP client.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up adding a plink call with the input piped into it:

`subprocess.check_call('echo y | ' + plink + ' -l ' + self._properties['ssh user'] + ' -pw ' + self._properties['ssh password'] + ' -ssh ' + self._properties['ssh user'] + '@' + self._properties['target ip'] + ' "echo > /dev/null"', shell=True)`

Which resulted in running plink in a do nothing and piping an accept to it in case it prompted for storing the key.  It feels kind of like kludge, but it appears to be functional.

Comment: Well, you can do the same with `pscp`, no need to run `plink` upfront. Though, again, this is a terrible security flaw.